# Javascript function not registering keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a function to *stop* when the enter key is pressed but for some reason it is not registering my `enter` variable's switch from false to true. I don't know if this is a scope issue or a closure issue or a binding issue, I've looked throughout the forums and tried a bunch of different solutions but nothing seems to work...

```
function positionArrow(arrow) {
  var enter = false;
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
        enter = true;
      }
  });
  console.log(enter);
  if (enter == true) {
    return;
  } else {
    $(arrow.element).css({
        left: arrow.x - arrowWidth / 2,
        top: arrow.y - arrowHeight / 2
      });
    rotate(arrow.element, arrow.angle);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will never work because the `(enter == true)` condition will never be met. The event handler is triggered asynchronously and guaranteed to happen after that check.

Comment: OK, this makes a lot more sense – thank you @alex! Would you recommend then putting the event handler in a separate function and have the `event` variable (true or false) passed to the positionArrow function? Or is there no way to get this to work?

Comment: @alex It's not so much that it's asynchronous, it that the code they actually want to run is out of the scope of the handler

Comment: Updated my answer but noticed something else, how are you getting/what is "arrow"

Answer (score 0):

You should have the code you want to run *within* your handler, and also your handler should be outside of your "positionArrow" function. Try replacing`enter = true;` with

```
$(arrow.element).css({
    left: arrow.x - arrowWidth / 2,
    top: arrow.y - arrowHeight / 2
});
rotate(arrow.element, arrow.angle);
```

And moving your handler declaration outside of the function. Code should look like this

```
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
        positionArrow(arrow);
      }
  }
  function positionArrow(arrow) {
    $(arrow.element).css({
        left: arrow.x - arrowWidth / 2,
        top: arrow.y - arrowHeight / 2
      });
    rotate(arrow.element, arrow.angle);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with the method below. I made `enter` a global variable and created a separate function. While this works, I feel there may be a better solution out there or a better articulation of what the problem was to begin with.

```
var enter = false;    

function stopArrow(){
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
          enter = true;
        }
    });
}

stopArrow();

function positionArrow(arrow) {
  if (enter == true) {
    return;
  } else {
    $(arrow.element).css({
        left: arrow.x - arrowWidth / 2,
        top: arrow.y - arrowHeight / 2
      });
    rotate(arrow.element, arrow.angle);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should check out my answer. Storing enter as a global variable doesn't really make sense because the key isn't always going to be pressed after you set it to true.

You're already checking if the key is pressed with "e.which == 13" which is the key code for enter. Just place the code you want to run inside that if statement